# Is possible to implement volume up|down in Google Actions V2

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm working with `MediaResponse` to play media (play song) with `Google Actions V2`.

I **did** these features:

- Play audio
- Stop
- Pause
- Resume
- Play
- Next
- Previous
- Repeat

But I wonder that why `MediaResponse` did not support `Volume intergration` while I said

- Increase|Decrease Volume
- Volume Up|Down

Is there anyway for me to implement these features?

*p/s :*

*- [Spotify service](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/00000040c43310fa?hl=en) can did it.*

*- I able to detect Intent with specify phrases : "Volume Up" ...*

**MediaResponse.js**

```
    class MediaPlayerUtils {

    getMediaResponse(song) {
        // This object used to play Media on Google Home
        var mediaResponse = new MediaResponse();
        mediaResponse.mediaType = "AUDIO";

        var mediaObject = new MediaObject({
            url: ""
        });

        mediaObject.name = song.title;
        mediaObject.contentUrl = song.url;

        mediaResponse.mediaObjects = [];
        mediaResponse.mediaObjects.push(mediaObject);

        var Media = function (song, mediaResponse) {
            this.song = song;
            this.mediaResponse = mediaResponse;
        }

        // Media Response : Play audio
        return new Media(song, mediaResponse);
    }

    playSong(conv, song) {
        console.log("playSong() " + song.title + " --- " + song.url);

        var media = function (song, mediaResponse) {
            this.song = song;
            this.mediaResponse = mediaResponse;
        }
        media = this.getMediaResponse(song);

        // Media Response : Play audio
        conv.ask(new SimpleResponse(" ")); // Able to set song title before playing song in here
        conv.ask(media.mediaResponse);
        conv.ask(new Suggestions(
           'next',
           'back',
           'previous',
           'play',
           'pause',
           'resume',
           'stop',
           'volumeDown',
           'volumeUp'));
        conv.ask(new SimpleResponse(""));
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After file a query to Google,

They answered that this time does not support.

It should be release in close future.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actions on Google doesn't, under normal conditions, allow for programatic control of volume. The reason you see it in Spotify is probably because Google and Spotify have a special relationship that lets them get around some of the normal constraints.